# saving plot with plt.savefig keeps saving blank plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

plt.figure()
with plt.rc_context({'figure.facecolor':'black', 'figure.dpi':1234,'text.color':'black'}):
plot_model(tuned_dt, plot='tree',)

Where can I save this plot using

```
plt.savefig()
```

or alternative, where ever I place it i seem to just save a blank plot

[image: plot output]

Comment: Where is `plot_model()` from? What is `tuned_dt`? It seems likely that you need to capture the generated fig from the call to `plot_model` and save it within the context manager's block, but it's hard to say without knowing what we're looking at exactly.

Comment: plot_model() is from pycaret. It creates the plot (decision tree) but is font is too small to read, so am trying to savefig with high dpi to create a version I can zoom in on to read. Have just added image above

Comment: plot_model(tuned_dt, plot='tree', save=True) ?